# Is $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ a Dedekind ring?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Is $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ a Dedekind ring? (for a prime number $p$) By $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ i mean the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at $p$.

I know that one must check a couple of conditions, like it being an integral domain, integrally closed, Noetherian, and has Krull dimension 1.

Thus far I know that it is a local ring with an unique maximal ideal. How do I continue?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You can simply show that it is a PID (DVR, in fact), and those are Dedekind domains.

Comment: Do you know that normality and noetherianity are preserved by localization?

Comment: @PavelC Thanks! (Because a PID that is not a ring is Dedekind?) What will be the generator though?

Comment: @Crostul No, i don't see why localization preserves the properties. Would you be able to elaborate a bit further?

Comment: If by generator you mean the uniformizing element, i.e. the generator of the maximal ideal, you can simply take $\frac{p}{1}$.